# Are lumens linearly additive?

Tags: luminosity

If I have two light sources side by side emitting $1000~\rm lumens$ each, am I going to have the same amount of light emitted in an enclosed space (e.g. a room) as if I had a single light source that's emitting $2000~\rm lumens$?

To ask a slightly different way: would $1000~{\rm lm} + 1000~\rm lm$ vs $2000~\rm lm$ be distinguishable to a small or large extent by looking at or measuring the brightness of a surface of the room?

Or yet another way: is the relationship between the two lights a linear function or some non-linear one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressed in lumens, and assuming that the light sources are close to each other compared to the distance they are being viewed from, the relation is linear, yes. Ultimately, for a specific wavelength, the lumen is a unit of power, so energy conservation makes the relation linear.

Your last question isn't the same as the first two. Just because it is twice as many lumens doesn't mean that it appears twice as bright to the human eye or anything like that. That is to say, there is more than one way to express the "relationship" between two lights, and not all of them add linearly.

Comment: Does this follow from lumen's definition as a unit of measure somehow? I'd like to somehow understand more deeply why this relationship is linear, not just know that it is. E.g. I've read somewhere that 1lm is equivalent to about `10^15` photons being emitted per second. Is that correct? And does linearity follow simply from 1lm+1lm and 2lm both emitting roughly `2*10^15`? Also, can the distance or other features of the light sources muddy this relationship somehow?

Comment: Yes but.....your eyes perceive light in log terms, so strictly speaking from the post wording, you won't see twice as much light.

Comment: @Countto10 while that may be true, does that matter for my question? 2000lm may only be perceived 1.5x (?) brighter by the human eye to 1000lm, but if 1000lm+1000lm and 2000lm turn out to be the same, then they will both be perceived to have the same 1.5x (?) brightness compared to a single 1000lm source. No?

Comment: @Wizek Yes, it follows from the definition. A lumen is $\frac{1}{683}~\rm W$ at a frequency of $540~\rm THz$ (or a different amount at a different frequency). So two lumen is ${2\over 683}~\rm W$ at that same frequency. Since two light bulbs give you twice the power (energy per time) as one does (by conservation of energy), and the two lightbulbs still have the same spectrum as one, two light bulbs give you twice the luminous flux.

Comment: @Chris, with your last edit, are you referring to me or to @Countto10? Because if you are referring to me, I'm curious to know which question of mine you had in mind, as I was trying to be careful not to confuse the amount of light being emitted with amount of brightness perceived of the human eye in my questions.

Comment: @Wizek Just that "is the relationship between the two lights a linear function or some non-linear one?" is not as well-defined a question as the rest. As a whole it's clear what you're really asking, though. On the other hand, keep in mind that the lumen as a unit *is* partially concerned with the amount of brightness perceived by the human eye. That's why a purple light of the same power as a green light has fewer lumens.

Comment: @Wizek Also, fyi if you surround things in dollar signs (\$) instead of backticks (\`) you can do math formatting. For instance "2*10^{15}" becomes $2*10^{15}$.

Comment: @Chris, Interesting, thank you for the answer and the comments! I shall ponder about this. And I'll try to remember your math formatting tip as well.